# Spoiler command not working

Tags: bug, spoilers

In [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/71743/52203) answer (which I suggested an edit for), the owner of the answer did not use spoiler tags. I suggested an edit with the spoiler tags added, but they are not functioning as expected. Instead of hiding the text in the quote, the ! (from `>!`) is showing up. Any ideas why this happens?